# $.ajax => fail trigger instead of done

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax call successfully working but not triggering my `.done` promise.
Instead, it keeps calling `.fail`

```
$.ajax({
        url: BASE_URL+"/"+usernameTemp+"/"+pass,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json"
})
.done( (res) => {
    console.log(res);
}).fail ( (err) => {
    console.log('err'+JSON.stringify(err));
});
```

On the console, the only thing displayed is :

```
err{"readyState":4,"responseText":"{success: true}","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}
```

Where `success: true` is the answer from the server.
Why isn't it triggering the done promise ?

Comment: the http  header respond is 200?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not much about the HTTP request failing, but the complete handling of the call, jQuery can fail to validate the response if it does not fit the expected type, or if it cannot be parsed. You are telling jQuery that your call should receive JSON data. But you are receiving INVALID json...

```
{success: true} //Wrong
{"success": true} //Good
```

Try it yourself, the code below create buttons when clicked simply calls JSON.parse with its content and log the result. You'll see that the first one cannot parse.

```js
$('button').on('click', function(e) {
  console.log(JSON.parse($(e.target).html()));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>{success: true}</button>

<button>{"success": true}</button>
```

Comment: Invalid JSON almost always means that the server script is trying to create the JSON by hand instead of using a library function that does it properly.

Comment: @Barmar that is a good remark, thank you for your addition. Now, it'd be outside of the scope of the question to go in more details.